# how to make a prompt edit text dialog when open the application and store the data to preference?

Tags: android, dialog, preference

I have read many articles, but all are about to set a preference screen and click on a preference item say the edit text then it prompts the edit text dialog. Now **i just want tohave a dialog that will prompt when the app is first created and store the input data to preference**. could I use DialogPreference in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course you can... At first, in onCreate of your activity create -

```
boolean firstrun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("firstrun", true);
```

Then check -

```
if (firstrun) {
//Call HERE your showDialog, for example...
 showDialog(DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY1);
}
```

And the last - just override onCreateDialog by ... -

```
 @Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    //main title
    case DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY1:
         LayoutInflater factorymain = LayoutInflater.from(this);
         final View textEntryViewMain = factorymain.inflate(R.layout.main_title_dialog, null);  
.................
............
```

By Layoutinflater as shown above you can show any layout with any editText objects you want....

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to save the "firstrun" marker in the preferences after getting its "true" value:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean firstrun = prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true);

if (firstrun) {
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit()
  editor.putBoolean("firstrun", false);
  editor.apply();

  //Call HERE your showDialog, for example...
  showDialog(DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY1);
}
```

So you will not get always a "true" value.
BTW, is a best practice to put all constants as static final properties so you will not have the change to misspell "firstrun", for example.